# Integration of $1/(x^2+x\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is to evaluate $\displaystyle7\int\frac{dx}{x^2+x\sqrt{x}}$.  My solution is attached.

[image: This is the question.]

[image: This is the solution that I tried.]

The problem of my solution is if I use partial fraction, loop will be made, and this makes whole equation $0 = 0$. I want to know how to approach this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the substitution $y = \sqrt{x}$. Then $x=y^2$ so that $dx = 2y\,dy$, and
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x^2+x\sqrt{x}} = \int \frac{2y\,dy}{y^4+y^3} = 2\int \frac{dy}{y^2(y+1)}.
$$
You should be able to carry on from here?

Answer (score 1):

Try the substitution: $\sqrt{x}=t$